# how to do incremental deep learning on data stream that can adapt to constantly generated data points?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am currently trying to learn a deep learning model on a data stream, which constantly generate new data points over time.  The goal is to generate a real-time DL model that can well adapt to newly generated data while does not affect the prediction for old data too much.  I am wondering if anyone know what might be the best way to do this "incremental deep learning on data stream"?  Any information would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing does not require a change in the deep learning models you would use but a change in how to estimate them: you need an **online estimation** procedure rather than an off-line one. You can have a look at the seminal work of [Botou [1998]](https://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/online-1998.pdf), or Chapter 8 of the book by [Goodfellow et al. (2016)](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/).